# how can i get value file from form-data with multiple different name field using ajax and validate them with JQUERY

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, ajax, form-data

Here is my form to send upload multiple images with different field name. Tks all (i am a newbie in PHP):

```html
<form action="" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data">
    <label for="email">
      Email:  <input type="email" name="email"/>
    </label>
    First_Image: <input type="file" name="image_one"/>
    Second_Image: <input type="file" name="image_two"/>
    <input type="submit" value="Submit"/>
</form>
```